# jQuery toggle children of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="dim">
    Menu
        <div class='hidden'>submenu1</div>
        <div class='hidden'>submenu2</div>
</div>
<div class="dim">
    Menu2
        <div class='hidden'>submenu3</div>
        <div class='hidden'>submenu4</div>
</div>
```

class `hidden` has `display:none`

I'm trying to get the toggle to work when I click on the word menu or menu2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('.dim').click(function(){
    $('.hidden', this).toggle(); // p00f
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/V4X4t/

---

#### Update

Checks for `dim` element being clicked:

```
$('.dim').click(function(event){
    
    var isDim = $(event.target).is('.dim');
    if(isDim){ //make sure I am a dim element
        $('.hidden', this).toggle(); // p00f
    }
    
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/V4X4t/5/

Comment: sorry, I had a mistake in my post, I just corrected it. can you have a look?

Comment: @hoverhand - The code above (after my edit) will work with your updated HTML.

Comment: @JosephSilber or Neal, is it possible to use toggle() in a way that will not remove the class but simply remove the display:none attribute?

Comment: @Neal - `$('.hidden', this)` maps internally to `$(this).find('.hidden')`. But `$(this).children('.hidden')` is faster.  If you like your style better, at least use the child selector: `$('> .hidden', this)`.

Comment: The ``dim`` div is within another div which I am also using a toggle for, so when I try to click on the ``dim`` classed div, instead of toggling the submenus, it toggles the parent of ``dim``. any ideas?

Comment: @hoverhand see my fiddle and update it to your needs so you can show what you are trying to do.

Comment: @hoverhand http://jsfiddle.net/76uTr/1/ It seems like you can use `event.stopPropagation()` to your advantage here. Code in my answer is updated as well.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.target.className ===` are two good ways to take care of event-bubbling.

Comment: @Neal - Why not simply `if(event.target === this)`?

Comment: @Neal - ...which is even slower than `hasClass`. `event.target === this` is native code.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.dim').on('click', function () {
    //$(this).children('.hidden').toggleClass('.hidden');//as-per AndreasAL's suggestion
    $(this).children('.hidden').toggle();
});

$('.hidden').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/76uTr/

This shows/hides the `.hidden` elements when clicking on a `.dim` element but it also allows you to click on a `.hidden` element and not toggle it's visibility.

Notice that I used `.children()` instead of `.find()` which will only select direct descendants of the root element (`.dim`).

Also note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`.

**UPDATE**

Using `event.stopPropagation()` we can allow ourselves to nest elements and not let events bubble-up and trigger multiple event handlers:

```
$('.dim').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.hidden').toggle();
});

$('.parent').on('click', function () {
    $(this).children('.dim').toggle();
});

$('.hidden').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/76uTr/1/

Here the `.parent` element is assumed to be the direct parent of the `.dim` elements.

Comment: nice with the stop bobbling catch. But the correct way will be to toggle the class not the css.

Answer (score 1):

Simply attach a click event handler, and check if the current element is the one that was clicked:

```
$('.dim').click(function(e)
{
    if (e.target == this)
    {
        $(this).children().toggle();
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4X4t/6/

Answer (score 0):

Create anchors at Menu and Menu2

```
<div class="dim">
    <a href="#" >Menu</a>
        <div class='hidden'>submenu1</div>
        <div class='hidden'>submenu2</div>
</div>
<div class="dim">
    <a href="#" >Menu2</a>
        <div class='hidden'>submenu3</div>
        <div class='hidden'>submenu4</div>
</div>
```

and script:

```
$(".dim > a").click( function ( e ){ 
   e.preventDefault() // prevent default action - hash doesn't appear in url
   $( this ).parent().find( "div" ).toggleClass( "hidden" );
});
```

When click anyone of link submenu belonging to it will will appear or disappear

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxwpJ/