# Javascript Toggle opening all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an accordion and I'm using the same classes for each row. Like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".faq-article").click(function() {
    $(".faq-details").toggle();
  })
});
```

```css
.faq-details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="faq-article">
    <div class="title-faq">Question 1</div>
    <div class="faq-details">answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-article">
    <div class="title-faq">Question 2</div>
    <div class="faq-details">answer 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't remember how to prevent showing all the `faq-details` when clicking on the first question title.

Comment: You are deliberately toggling all elements. Targeting a specific one is a basic and essential mechanism of jQuery. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @ChrisG Is one of those small things that I forget sometimes.

Comment: Everybody forgets stuff, including me of course. My point is that you should have google this instead of posting a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` as context of your search for the `.faq-details` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".faq-article").click(function() {
    $(".faq-details", this).toggle();
  })
});
```

```css
.faq-details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="faq-article">
    <div class="title-faq">Question 1</div>
    <div class="faq-details">answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-article">
    <div class="title-faq">Question 2</div>
    <div class="faq-details">answer 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Took less time to find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649178/jquery-toggle-children-of-div than to write code

Comment: @mplungjan To be honest, I don't even know how to search that on google. It's one of those small things that I forget sometimes.

Comment: I searched `jQuery toggle child div` :)

Comment: @mplungjan I wasn't even near that, oh. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As there are multiple elements with class `faq-article`, when implementing `toggle()` on that class all elements are affected. To get the currently clicked element you have to target the current context of the `click` event by specifying [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Change
`$(".faq-details").toggle();`

To

`$(this).find(".faq-details").toggle();` **OR** `$(".faq-details", this).toggle();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".faq-article").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".faq-details").toggle();
  })
});
```

```css
.faq-details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="faq-article">
    <div class="title-faq">Question 1</div>
    <div class="faq-details">answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq-article">
    <div class="title-faq">Question 2</div>
    <div class="faq-details">answer 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now it is identical to the other answer. Both duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649178/jquery-toggle-children-of-div?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa